# Search value in list

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to search value in list:

```
          String search = 'blue Table15';

                    List list = [
                      {"Label": "blue Table 15", "Value": "1"},
                      {"Label": "Table blue 15", "Value": "2"},
                      {"Label": " blue15 Table", "Value": "3"},
                      {"Label": "Chair red 14", "Value": "4"},
                      {"Label": "Chair 16 red ", "Value": "5"},
                      {"Label": " 17 Chair red", "Value": "6"},
                    ];

                    List<dynamic> values = list
                        .where((oldValue) =>
                            (oldValue['Label'].toString().contains(search)))
                        .toList();

                    print(values);
```

expected return:

[{Label: blue Table 15, Value: 1}, {Label: Table blue 15, Value: 2}, {Label: blue15 Table, Value: 3}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You firstly need to split your search text into single words. Then check all splited single word with contain function in where filter like here; (If you have more than values in search string, you can also use loops to check all splited word)

```
   String search = 'blue Table 15';
   List<String> splitedValue = search.split(" ");
   List list = [
         {"Label": "blue Table 15", "Value": "1"},
         {"Label": "Table blue 15", "Value": "2"},
         {"Label": " blue15 Table", "Value": "3"},
         {"Label": "Chair red 14", "Value": "4"},
         {"Label": "Chair 16 red ", "Value": "5"},
         {"Label": " 17 Chair red", "Value": "6"},
   ];

   List<dynamic> values = list
                        .where((oldValue) =>
                            (oldValue['Label'].contains(splitedValue[0]) || 
                         oldValue['Label'].contains(splitedValue[1]) ||
                         oldValue['Label'].contains(splitedValue[2])))
                        .toList();

   print(values);
   //[{Label: blue Table 15, Value: 1}, {Label: Table blue 15, Value: 2}, {Label:  blue15 Table, Value: 3}]
```

To seperate numbers from the text, you can use the function below;

```
List<String> splitTextAndNumber(String text){
  String stringText = "";
  String numberText = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    var char = text[i];
    try{
      var parsedValue = int.parse(char);
      numberText += char;
    }catch(e){
      stringText += char;
    }
    
  }
  return [stringText, numberText];
}
```

You can basically call function in this way below;

```
  String text = "table15";
  List<String> splitedValues = splitTextAndNumber(text);
  print(splitedValues); // returns [table, 15]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How I split "Table15" from number and string "table", "15"?

Comment: I edited my post, I added a function that seperate the numbers from string, if my post helped you, could you please upvote it.